# Is it possible to make a cell turns empty if the calculated result of an INDEX is #N/A?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The original formula is this:

```
 {= INDEX(Country;MATCH(0;COUNTIF($A$1:A32;Country);0))}
```

Sometimes, the result is #N/A. However, I would like to make the cell which does not contain available value to be empty. I tried with IFError:

Which does not work.

```
 {= IFERROR(INDEX(Country;MATCH(0;COUNTIF($A$1:A32;Country);0)), "")}
```

Is it possible to achieve my purpose? If so, how?

Sample data for country:

```
country1, 
country2, 
country3, 
country4, 
country5, 
country6, 
country7, 
country8,
```

Answer (score 1):

this should fix this, not tested

`{=IF(ISNA(MATCH(0;COUNTIF($A$1:A32;Country));"";INDEX(Country;MATCH(0;COUNTIF($A$1:A32;Country);0)))}`

Comment: I think the two comma in the middle should be semi-colon right? If yes, it does not work (too many arguments); If no, it also does not work(problem with this formula).

Comment: Actually, thanks for your answer, I arrived at the correct solution.

Comment: no probs. If this helped you can vote or Accept it. kinda how thx Works around here ;)

Answer (score 0):

Actually this work:

```
= IFERROR(INDEX(Country;MATCH(0;COUNTIF($A$1:A31;Country);0)); "")
```

The reason of my problem is that I used comma instead of semicolon for separator for arguments of the function.